# generate two sets of combination with one list in python

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

Let's say there are 9 different cards and 2 different players. When 3 cards are given for each player (a total of 6 cards) out of 9 cards.

How can I generate all combinations of distributing 6 cards to 2 players?

The number of combinations is easily calculated:

```
number_of_combinations = (9!/(6!*3!)) * (6!/(3!*3!)) = 1680
```

- Player1 gets 3 cards within 9 cards. Number of possible combinations is `9!/(6!*3!)`.
- Player2 gets 3 cards within 6 remaining cards. Number of possible combinations is `6!/(3!*3!)`.

Therefore, all combinations of distributing 6 cards to 2 players is `(9!/(6!*3!)) * (6!/(3!*3!)`.

But generating combinations looks very difficult; this is what I have tried:

```
comb = itertools.combination([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 6)
```

But there is one problem:

Let's say there are two lists, case1 and case2.

```
case1 = [1,2,3 ,4,5,6]
case2 = [1,2,4 ,3,5,6]
```

In my case, I have to handle case1 and case2 differently.

But if I just generate 6 size combinations, I can't do that.

Comment: Your formula for the n_o_c is missing the `/(n-k)!` factors.

Comment: @DSM and the result is coincidentally correct :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To produce *one* dealing, you'd use the [`random.sample()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) to pick 6 cards at random; give the first 3 to player 1, the remainder to player 2:

```
dealt_cards = random.sample(deck_of_cards, 6)
player1_hand, player2_hand = dealt_cards[:3], dealt_cards[3:]
```

To produce *all* possible combinations then, you'd use [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) with size 6; but you still need to find all possible permutations of dividing those 6 cards over 2 hands that are unique:

```
for dealt_cards in itertools.combinations(deck_of_cards, 6):
    for hand1 in itertools.combinations(dealt_cards, 3):
        hand2 = tuple(card for card in dealt_cards if card not in hand1)
```

so from each dealt combination of 6 cards, all combinations of 3 cards are given to one player, leaving the remaining 3 cards for the other player.

This produces the expected number of solutions:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> deck = range(9)
>>> sum(1 for dealt in combinations(deck, 6) for _ in combinations(dealt, 3))
1680
```

and demo:

```
>>> for dealt_cards in combinations(deck, 6):
...     for hand1 in combinations(dealt_cards, 3):
...         hand2 = tuple(card for card in dealt_cards if card not in hand1)
...         print hand1, hand2
... 
(0, 1, 2) (3, 4, 5)
(0, 1, 3) (2, 4, 5)
(0, 1, 4) (2, 3, 5)
(0, 1, 5) (2, 3, 4)
(0, 2, 3) (1, 4, 5)
# ...
(4, 6, 7) (3, 5, 8)
(4, 6, 8) (3, 5, 7)
(4, 7, 8) (3, 5, 6)
(5, 6, 7) (3, 4, 8)
(5, 6, 8) (3, 4, 7)
(5, 7, 8) (3, 4, 6)
(6, 7, 8) (3, 4, 5)
```

You could also produce just the player 1 hands, then continue with the remainder of the deck to produce the player 2 hands:

```
for hand1 in itertools.combinations(deck_of_cards, 3):
    for hand2 in itertools.combinations([c for c in deck_of_cards if c not in hand1], 3):
        # ...
```

with the same expected count output and results:

```
>>> sum(1 for dealt in combinations(deck, 3) for _ in combinations([c for c in deck if c not in dealt], 3))
1680
>>> for hand1 in combinations(deck, 3):
...     for hand2 in combinations([c for c in deck if c not in hand1], 3):
...         print hand1, hand2
... 
(0, 1, 2) (3, 4, 5)
(0, 1, 2) (3, 4, 6)
(0, 1, 2) (3, 4, 7)
(0, 1, 2) (3, 4, 8)
(0, 1, 2) (3, 5, 6)
# ...
(6, 7, 8) (1, 3, 4)
(6, 7, 8) (1, 3, 5)
(6, 7, 8) (1, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8) (2, 3, 4)
(6, 7, 8) (2, 3, 5)
(6, 7, 8) (2, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8) (3, 4, 5)
```

albeit in a different order now.

Comment: If I understand correct, the OP needs to enumerate all possible hands for two players.

Comment: Yes. I need all possible combinations of cards.

Comment: @Martijn, I also tried itertools.combinations. I think just generating combinations with size 6 is not the solution.

Comment: @JaeJunLEE if you tried `itertools`, what didn't work?

Comment: @JaeJunLEE: right, because the dealt cards are divided over 2 hands. Added that in, sorry for being a little obtuse right now.

Comment: @bereal: anything missing still?

Comment: @MartijnPieters looks fine to me.

Comment: @ Martijn Thank you very much!. It's working. I hope to vote up your answer. But my reputation is not enough. Sorry... and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
combinations = itertools.combinations(cards, 6)
```

This would give you 6 chosen cards, then you need to distribute those 6 cards amongst the 2 players, so:

```
possibilities = []
for combination in combinations:
    hands = []
    hand1 = itertools.combinations(combination, 3)
    hands.append(hand1)#Hand1
    hands.append([x for x in combination if x not in hand1])#Hand2
    possibilities.append(hands)
```

This will generate a list `possibilities` for where each item is a list of the 2 different hands.

Comment: This won't work as written, although I think it's the right idea.

Comment: Yes I had a much simpler version and edited it but messed something up. I updated it and it should work now.

Comment: Right now you're mixing the combinations object and the hand.  `print(possibilities[0])`, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Just getting all possible combinations of 6 cards won't cut it, since the order in a single player's hand doesn't matter, but it matters who has which cards.

So for all combinations of 3 cards out of 9, choose 3 *other* cards out of the remaining 6:

```
from itertools import combinations

def getCardCombinations(cards):
    cards = set(cards)
    for first in combinations(cards, 3):
        for second in combinations(cards - set(first), 3):
            yield first, second

cards = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

all_combinations = getCardCombinations(cards)
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you right, you want to get every possible combination of choosing 6 out of 9. Since the order doesn't really matter (we can treat the first 3 as player 1's and the second batch of 3 as player 2's hand), we can just use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations, izip
hands = combinations(cards, 6)
```

Am I understanding your question right?

edit: to divide these into two hands of 3 each, you'd use:

```
player1, player2 = izip(*map(lambda x: (x[:3], x[3:]), combinations(cards, 6)))
```

Comment: You cannot just pick 6 out of 9, that is only 84 combinations, not the expected 1680.

Comment: Good point, I missed that. I'd edit to fix but it looks like there's a correct answer up already so I'll just upvote and move on.